# Custom CollectionViewCell with different cell identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am currently using a custom collection view cell with separate nib file and implementation files. I am also handling a certain type of animation for scrolling. When there are many cells, some of them overlaps. So i am exploring an option of using various cell identifiers for different cells based on the cell index path. Is there any way to achieve this because the registering function require the user to define the cell identifier in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the registerClass method for different types of custom cells and different custom cell identifier. example in Swift:

```
    searchResultsTableView.registerClass(HolidayItemTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "holidayItemCell")
    searchResultsTableView.registerClass(EmployeeSearchResultsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "employeeSearchResultCell")
    searchResultsTableView.registerClass(OfficeSearchResultTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "officeCell")
```